# How does ASP.NET track session in multiple browsers/tabs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

How does ASP.NET web application track session in multiple browsers/tabs? For example, if I am logged on to some site, when I open a new instance of browser, it knows (or assumes) that I am still the same user therefore, it is the same session and still uses my credentials when I access the site in the new browser instance. But when I start new session in IE (in file menu), it uses a new session.

How is this done b ASP.NET and what does open a new session in IE actually does (I mean internally, I know that it will start a new session)? And is it the same for WebForms and ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Which menu item do you mean exactly? Anyway, sessions are handled with cookies.

Comment: @Stijn: In IE, there is a "New Session" menu item in the File menu. As I have read, sessions may or may not use cookies, but my question relates as to how ASP.NET determines if a new browser instance is a new or an existing session.

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't. It's a browser decision whether tabs/windows/sessions share session cookies or have independent sets (most browsers these days will share session cookies between tabs and windows). It's then usually left for ASP.Net to be confused when a single session is performing actions on multiple separate pages.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Could you provide a source to this? I'd like to be able to read further, and please put it in an answer (instead of comment) so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, ASP.NET tracks your session with a session cookie.

According to [this post on IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx), the new window will not share session cookies with the existing window, when you go through *File -> New session*. That's why you won't be logged on in the new window.

The blog explains some more what session merging is, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never seen the "New Session" open in IE!

Your session is essentially an ID between the server and your browser (try it, `response.write('Session.SessionID');`) - this ID I held by the server for the session until timeout (usually 20 mins) and if you're using session cookies, then the cookie data is stored in server memory under that ID rather than persistent cookies, which are stored as text files local to the browser and sent to the server on request.

For ASP.net authentication, there is an `AUTH` cookie, this can be persistent - you want the login to remain even in a new browsing session - or not and will require login each session.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

To the question, this session ID is persisted across all tabs and browsing instances in IE unless you start a new session, which will have a different session ID for the server, hence new session details etc...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'd mark this also as the answer if SO allowed for multiple answers but Stijn already provided me an answer in the comments and I just asked him to put it in answer form... Thanks though, will vote up.